# Scikit Learn import error: 'cross_val_predict' is not defined

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to run some simple codes of scikit-learn in python, and while executing this, I encountered this error:

> from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
>   ImportError: cannot import name cross_val_predict

I have downloaded scikit learn from this page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scikit-learn/?source=typ_redirect and the other modules like sklearn.linear_model works well. It seems that I can also import successfully the module cross_validation.. I cannot understand!

Comment: Can you please post a concise code example that raises this error?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is actually the first example from the scikit learn website, which you can find here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/plot_cv_predict.html#example-plot-cv-predict-py  In fact the error occurs in the second line. And I can run correctly (at least it seems) the third and fourth example that you can find in the example list. So I think I have just to complete the package with the cross_val_predict function.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. When I typed help sklearn.cross_validation, in the documentation there is no function cross_val_predict. As a real new-comer, I have no idea how to add that function into my package.. It has been tens days that I try to install numpy/scipy/sklearn in python windows.. :'( Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Check your version, i.e., `print sklearn.__version__`. It appears this function is is new to the 0.16 version.

Comment: I forgot to upload the 0.16.0 release to sourceforge. We tend to use PyPI nowadays: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! It seems works now ! In fact, instead of using the .exe files that I downloaded from internet (which turned out to be perhaps incompatible), I finally successed to install many modules by the standard "pip install". The only thing that I could not use "pip install" is the package "Scipy", so I had to replace it by a .exe file. Thank you for all your help !

Comment: Note that you also have the option of building numpy / scipy from source. This has the added benefit of pointing towards your machine's ATLAS / LAPACK / BLAS libraries which may be faster if they were installed specific to your machine.